# Obtener links de todas las imagenes almacenadas en FIREBASE

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Android Studio y FireBase.

La estructura de la base de datos en FireBase seria algo así:

```
<code>
"usuario_1":{   
    "id":"Gasdj21jk1231Hsd13",
    "datosusuario":{    
        "nombre":"JoseCarlos Diaz",
        "email":"jdiaz@gmail.com"
        "imagenprofile":"direccion de la imagen de perfil"
    }
        "esCliente" : true,
        "intereses":[   "deporte",
                        "musica",
                        "comida"
        ],
    "imagenes":[
        "hijoimagen_0123" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0124" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0125" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        }
    ]   
},
"usuario_2":{   
    "id":"Gasdj21jk1231Hsd13",
    "datosusuario":{    
        "nombre":"JoseCarlos Diaz",
        "email":"jdiaz@gmail.com"
        "imagenprofile":"direccion de la imagen de perfil"
    }
        "esCliente" : true,
        "intereses":[   "deporte",
                        "musica",
                        "comida"
        ],
    "imagenes":[
        "hijoimagen_0123" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0124" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0125" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        }
    ]   
},
.
.
.
.
.
</code>
```

Y mi objetivo es obtener todas las url de las imagenes que se encuentran en la estructura de la Base de Datos.
Osea recorrer cada child de usuario e ir obteniendo los links de las imágenes y al final poder tener un array de puro links los cuales contengan las url de las imágenes, para luego pueda aplicar filtros.

Alguien me puede ayudar a estructurar una query para FireBase y Android?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hay que hacer es recuperar todos los hijos del nodo imagenes, y recuperar las URLs:

```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference imagenes = database.getReference("usuario_1/imagenes");
    imagenes.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){

    onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName){
     HijoImagen hijo = snapshot.getValue(HijoImagen.class);
     //hacer lo que necesites con hijo.getUrlimagen()


}
...
});
```